# Function is not being recognised f#

Tags: function, f#

I am new to f# and was writing a program to solve xuvat equations, however my function was not being recognised by the compiler and I got an error `The value or constructor 'xuvat' is not defined.`

This is my function:

```
let xuvat xuvatTuple =
    match xuvatTuple with
    | (x, u, v, a, t) -> 
        match ((x<>null), (u<>null), (v<>null), (a<>null), (t<>null)) with
        | (true, true, true, _, _) -> (x, u, v, ((v**2 - u**2)/(2*x)), ((2*x)/(u + v)))
        | (true, true, _, true, _) -> (x, u, (u + a*t), a, ((sqrt (u**2 + (2 * a * x)) - u) / a))
        | (true, _, true, true, _) -> (x, (v - (a*t)), v, a, ((v - sqrt (v**2 - (2 * a * x))) / a))
        | (_, true, true, true, _) -> (((u**2 + v**2)/2*a), u, v, a, ((v-u)/a))
        | (_, true, true, _, true) -> (((u+v)/2), u, v, ((v-u)/t), t)
        | (_, true, _, true, true) -> ((u*t + (a*t*t)/2), u, (u + a*t), a, t)
        | (_, _, true, true, true) -> ((v*t - (a*t*t)/2), (v - a*t), v, a, t)
        | (true, _, _, true, true) -> (x, ((x - a*t*t)/2*t), ((x + a*t*t)/2*t), a, t)
        | (true, _, true, _, true) -> (x, (((2*x)/t) + v), v, ((2*v*t-2*x)/t**2), t)
        //| (true, true, _, _, true) -> (x, u, (((2*x)/t) - u), ((2*x -2*u*t)/t**2), t)
        | _ -> failwith "NOT ENOUGH INFORMATION"
```

This is the entry point for my code and where my function is being called:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let xuvatTuple = (7, 0, null, null, 4)
    
    let finalTuple = xuvat xuvatTuple
    printfn $"{finalTuple}"
```

Please can you help me to to find the answer.

Comment: Make sure `xuvat` comes before `main` in your source file, or if it's in another file, that file is ordered before the one with `main` in it.

Comment: @PhillipCarter `xuvat` is before main in my source file and there are no other functions

Comment: What's your project structure? Did you include the module which contains `xuvat` in your `main` file with an `open` statement?

Answer (score 6):

The primary issue is not that the `xuvat` function is not recognized, but the fact that `xuvat` has a type error and so the compiler does not accept it (and so it is later not defined).

When I copy your code into Visual Studio, it does not actually show the error (in IntelliSense), but only when I try to compile it, which is confusing.

The issue is that you are taking some arguments (as a tuple) and you do numerical operations with them, but also compare them with `null`. But numerical types do not allow `null` values, so this cannot work. Similarly, your `xuvatTuple` contains some `int` values and some `obj` values, which is also probably not what you wanted.

You could fix this by using `option` values instead:

```
let xuvat xuvatTuple =
  match xuvatTuple with
  | (Some x, Some u, Some v, _, _) -> 
      (x, u, v, ((v*v - u*u)/(2*x)), ((2*x)/(u + v)))

let xuvatTuple = (Some 7, Some 0, None, None, Some 4)
let finalTuple = xuvat xuvatTuple
```

I've only done the first case, but you get the idea. I think there is also a bug in your second case, because your computation refers to `t`, but this is supposedly `null` (which you see immediately if you use pattern matching like this!) I also changed `u**2` to `u*u`, because `**` is not defined on integers.

Comment: I have tried doing this but I still get the same error. Also, I get the error ` the type int does not support the operator 'Sqrt'`

Comment: I don't know the function you are trying to implement. Is this suppose to work on `int` or `float` values? If `int`, then you cannot take a square root of int... If `float`, then you can fix this by using floating-point values throughout your sample (i.e. replace `2` with `2.0`)

Answer (score 4):

I've reproduced what you're seeing. I think the problem is that `xuvat` contains numerous other compiler errors, which prevents the compiler from inferring its return type, which in turn prevents the compiler from recognizing your attempt to call `xuvat`.

You can expose these other errors by explicitly declaring `xuvat`'s return type, like this:

```ml
let xuvat xuvatTuple : (int * int * int * int * int) =
   ...
```

Once you do that, you can see the errors listed:

```
Program.fs(5,40): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not have 'null' as a proper value. See also Program.fs(4,19)-(4,23).
Program.fs(5,43): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not have 'null' as a proper value. See also Program.fs(4,30)-(4,34).
Program.fs(5,46): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not have 'null' as a proper value. See also Program.fs(4,41)-(4,45).
Program.fs(5,51): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not support the operator 'Pow'
Program.fs(5,58): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not support the operator 'Pow'
Program.fs(6,57): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not have 'null' as a proper value. See also Program.fs(4,52)-(4,56).
Program.fs(6,68): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not support the operator 'Pow'
Program.fs(6,84): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not support the operator 'Sqrt'
Program.fs(7,74): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not support the operator 'Pow'
Program.fs(7,90): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not support the operator 'Sqrt'
Program.fs(8,42): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not support the operator 'Pow'
Program.fs(8,49): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not support the operator 'Pow'
Program.fs(9,68): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not have 'null' as a proper value. See also Program.fs(4,63)-(4,67).
Program.fs(13,76): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not support the operator 'Pow'
Program.fs(22,28): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not have 'null' as a proper value
```